# 2 compareTo method overriden in the same class definition, how could I force to use the second?

Tags: java, list, sorting, collections

I want to sort a list `List<Blabla> donnees` by a criterion on one of its field. My problem is that compareTo is already overriden for this Class. So I've got something like :

```
Blabla {

    public int compareTo(Object other) {
        ...
     }

    public int compareTo(Blabla other) {
        ... 
     }

}
```

In a business layer class I call :

```
Business {
   method (){
       Collections.sort(List<Blabla > donnees);
   }

}
```

But this call N°1 compareTo method with object parameter. How could I sort my list with the N°2 method?

This is on an old and huge application, I don't know the side effects on changing anything in the  N°1compareTo method that's why I want to add another compareTo (or anything else )method instead of changing the first one.

Answer (score 4):

use **Comparator** instead of **Comparable**.

It will let you use as many as different ways u want to compare

Comment: This is on an old and huge application, I don't know the side effects on changing anything in the N°1compareTo method that's why I want to add another compareTo (or anything else )method instead of changing the first one.

Comment: +1: The use of Comparator is the only correct approach in this case. Here is potentially a useful link http://lkamal.blogspot.com/2008/07/java-sorting-comparator-vs-comparable.html

Comment: Then when you pass the BlaBla object as an argument to the compareto method it will call your implemented method and any other object when passed will call overriden method.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the answer to the question about why you end up calling the `compareTo(Object)` method instead of the specific one is because your class definition says `implements Comparable` (without any type parameter).  Without any generic type, any types like `T` will default to `Object`.

There are a couple of solutions to this.  The first one has already been recommended by others, and it involves making your own custom `Comparator<Blabla>` objects and using those in your sort methods.  Because these comparators are separate objects, they won't interfere with the existing class behaviour.  Take these comparators for example, on some class `Person` which has `getName()` and `getAge()` methods. You can create as many of these as you need.

```
public class AgeComparator implements Comparator<Person> {
    @Override
    public int compare(Person o1, Person o2) {
        return o1.getAge() - o2.getAge();
    }
}

public class NameComparator implements Comparator<Person> {
    @Override
    public int compare(Person o1, Person o2) {
        return o1.getName().compareTo(o2.getName());
    }
}
```

After you get that working, you can decide whether or not you wish to change your original class so that it properly implements `Comparable<Blabla>`.  At that point, you remove the `compareTo(Object)` method entirely and keep the other one.  When you compile, or when you save in your IDE, you'll then discover all the places where that object is referenced as `Comparable` without a type, and they'll show as compiler warnings or errors.  It's then down to you to decide how to fix the code in each case.  That very much depends on what the `compareTo(Object)` method does differently from the `compareTo(Blabla)` method.  If it explicitly does an `instanceof` check and/or cast directly to type `Blabla`, then the conversion should be 100% safe because that means all existing code must be using it correctly if you never experience any `ClassCastException`s at runtime.

Answer (score -1):

in the CompareTo(Object other) have an if statement saying

```
`if(other instanceof Blabla) Return compareTo((Blabla)other)`
```

Comment: -1: This approach breaks the Liskov principle (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle).